# Prevent Character Escaping on Spring JAXB

Tags: spring, jaxb

I'm using String class as request object type at my SOAP request.

I need to disable escaping of JAXB and wrote a code like this:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("packageName");
    map.put("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
            new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                                   Writer writer) throws IOException {
                    writer.write(ac, i, j);
                }
            });
    jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(map);

    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

But, I think Spring doesn't accept com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler property to disable character escaping. It gives error like this:

```
2022-01-07 19:39:41.124 ERROR 45808 --- [ter.container-1] c.p.d.g.s.SendMailService                : org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler value: com.paycore.delivery.gate.soap.SOAPConfig$1@2fbb54f6
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:955)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createMarshaller(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:731)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:701)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2.doWithMessage(WebServiceTemplate.java:399)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:590)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
```

How can I disable character escaping on Jaxb2Marshaller object?

Comment: Also facing this same issue

Comment: Can you share your pom file?

Answer (score 1):

According to jaxb-ri, and depending if targeting **jaxb2** (`javax` based) or **jaxb4** (`jakarta` based), you can use the following syntax :

**jaxb2**

```java
map.put(
    "com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler",
    new CustomCharacterEscapeHandler())
```

Sample source [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/EE8/jaxb-ri%2Fsamples%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fsamples%2Fcharacter-escape%2Fsrc%2FMain.java)

**jaxb3 and jaxb4**

```java
map.put(
    "org.glassfish.jaxb.characterEscapeHandler",
    new CustomCharacterEscapeHandler())
```

Sample source [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/master/jaxb-ri%2Fsamples%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fsamples%2Fcharacter-escape%2Fsrc%2FMain.java)